# Running a basic assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am working my way through "Programming from the ground up" and wrote my first program:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

I have a couple questions about this:

1. What assembly is this using? It says:

> "This book teaches assembly language for x86 processors and the GNU/Linux operating system."

However, if I go to https://godbolt.org and choose Assembly, there are literally hundreds of options -- ARM64 gcc 8.2, ARM gc 8.2, MIPS gcc 5.4, ... Why are there so many versions? Are these all "assembly for x86 linux"?

2. Sometimes I've seen commands written as `movl $0, %ebx` and as `movl %ebx, $0`. Why are these sometimes reversed?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks I'll add that into my question as well.

Comment: It is using ATT format that GAS uses as opposed to Intel format such as that used by NASM. They each have their own syntax, GAS you read left->right on the command arguments, Intel goes right->left. Some will have preference one way or the other, generally based on what you learn first. A very good fundamental assembly book is the DOS version of [Art of Assembly](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/index.html) (free .pdf) Chapters 2-5 especially. It is 100% applicable even though it is primarily x86. (newer versions not nearly as clear)

Comment: Direct link to the 1st Edition in .pdf [Art of Assembly x86 1st Edition](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf) The 2nd and later versions focus to much on using a set of HLA include files that obscure the fundamental assembly.For each processor you will have a specific set of instructions you can utilize beyond the general x86, x86_64 instructions, e.g. [Intel® 64 and IA-32](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) You also need [x86 and amd64 instruction reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) (or similar)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin awesome -- thanks for the link, that will be my next book!

Comment: Best part about it -- they are all free to download `:)`

Comment: MIPS, ARM, and ARM64 are other architectures.  They are incompatible to x86.  These architectures are used on processors of other vendors, such as those used in your telephone or router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ARM64 gcc 8.2, ARM gc 8.2, MIPS gcc 5.4, ... Are these all "assembly
>   for x86 linux"?

No, these are CPU target architectures. There are different CPU architectures, each with their own instruction set and registers. Different architectures are incompatible. Why so many? Well, because monopoly is bad and frankly there are not so many.

> Why are these sometimes reversed?

If you mean:

```
movl    $24, (%rdi)
```

vs

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 24
```

Then the first is AT&T syntax, the 2nd is Intel syntax (they both work on `x86`, AMD or Intel regardless and express the same thing, it's just the syntax used for human reading that's different).